# How to pass a form to a template without passing it to the views in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

At the moment I have some `Posts` to show to the users. The `GenericView` handling this page is a `DetailView` and I've already passed `FormMixin` into it to handle `Comment` functionality.

Now I want to add a Flag or Report form to bottom of each Post. I've found some ways to pass two different forms to a single generic view, but I found them messy and django suggest not to do such complex things. My question is how would I do this task?

Actually I was trying to render the form manually but I couldn't figure out how to pass reason id to the action of the form.

Report's Model:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='reporters')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    reason  = models.IntegerField(choices=REASON_CHOICES, default=BROKEN_LINK)
```

Report's Form:

```
BROKEN_LINK, RUDE, BAD_TRANSLATE, IRR = range(4)
REASON_CHOICES = (
        (BROKEN_LINK, 'Broken_link'),
        (RUDE, 'Rude'),
        (BAD_TRANSLATE, 'Bad_translate'),
        (IRR, 'Irr')
    )
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = Report
        fields = ['reason']
        widgets = {
            'reason': forms.RadioSelect,
        }
```

Report views.py:
( report_object and ReportCreateView are doing the same job, the first one was for the time that I decide to don't use generic views to create handle the form )

```
def report_object(request, model, object_id, reason):
    if request.post == POST:
       ...

class ReportCreateView(CreateView):
    model       = Report
    form_class  = ReportForm
    template_name = "forms/report_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
```

In `textdeatilview` I define reasons as:

```
context['reasons'] = REASON_CHOICES
```

Here's what I was thinking to do inside template:

```
<form class="report" method="POST" id="{{ post.id }}" action="{% url 'report_create' model="post"  object_id=post.id reason=??? %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {% for id, value in reasons %} 
        <p><input type="radio" name="reason" id="" value="{{ id }}" />{{ value }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
  </form>
```

Is this the right approach? If so, how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

No. The reason ID is part of the submitted form data, it's not part of the URL and it doesn't need to be a parameter to the view.

Comment: I've changed url pattern to:     `url(r'^report/(?P<model>text|link|comment)/(?P<object_id>\d+/$)', report_object, name='report_create')` and changed form action url to `{% url 'report_create' model="text" object_id=text.pk %}`under text posts. But I get NoReverseMatch. Is that generally OK now?

Comment: Should be `object_id=post.pk`, surely?

Comment: No that seems object_id is OK, there might be a problem with model. `Reverse for 'report_create' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'model': u'text', u'object_id': 2}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['flag/report/(?P<model>text|link|comment)/(?P<object_id>\\d+/$)']`